# Strings Becoming Empty when dtype is defined for numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, dtype

I am encountering the problem of strings becoming empty when I try to set the `dtype` of a `numpy.array`.

```
import numpy as np

data = [('peter', 182.37), ('parker', 179.24)]
arr = np.array(data, dtype=np.dtype([('name', np.unicode), ('height', np.float16)]))
print(arr)
```

gives the following array where the strings `'peter'` and `'parker'` are both now `''`.

> [('', 182.4) ('', 179.2)]

If no dtype is specified, the strings appear as expected in the `np.array`.

```
import numpy as np

data = [('peter', 182.37), ('parker', 179.24)]
arr = np.array(data)
print(arr)
```

> [['peter' '182.37']
>
> ['parker' '179.24']]

**Question:** Why are the strings becoming empty when the dtype for it is `np.unicode` or `np.string`? The string's dtype for `np.array` must support variable length strings. How can we fix this? Thank you!

Using *Python 3.7.4, numpy 1.17.2*

Comment: Set thee string length as well e.g. 'U10'

Comment: @hpaulj It works! But is can the string's dtype be variable-length? I think `'U10'` sets the max length to 10.

Comment: In `np.array(['one','three',...'])` it chooses a long enough one based on inputs.  In other cases you just have to do that yourself.  Unlike python strings, the numpy dtype is fixed.  You can use Python strings with 'object' dtype - that's what pandas does.

Comment: you could calculate your longest name `string_size = max([len(item[0]) for item in data])` then pass that as your dtype size `arr = np.array(data, dtype=np.dtype([('name', np.unicode, string_size), ('height', np.float16)]))`

Comment: Why are you using a numpy array to hold tuples with strings?